# Antiforgerytoken MVC C# search form

Tags: c#

I have a search box on my site. 
The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]         
public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchModel model)
{
```

View:

```
 <div class="siteSearch clearfix" role="search">

        <form id="HeaderSearchForm">

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <label for="tbSiteSearch">Search:</label>

            <input type="text" id="tbSiteSearch" name="tbSiteSearch" class="text" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn submit">
                <i class="icon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

So when I do a search, I can see the hidden label with the Anti Forgery Token present. This all works as expected because if I take a blank html page, copy the form code and leave the '__RequestVerificationToken' blank, I get told that the token hasn't been set and the search doesn't run. Which is what I would expect. 
The issue I have is if I submit a search, copy the token from my site and place it in to my blank html page e.g.

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <script>history.pushState('', '', '/')</script>
    <form action="https://www.adomainname.co.uk/Search/SearchResults/" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="SearchTerm" value="testing" />
    <input type="hidden" name="&#95;&#95;RequestVerificationToken" value="theverificationtokengoeshere" /> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The request is submitted - even if I am running the above code on localhost. I would have expected the form to not submit as it was coming from a different domain. Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

If I refresh the page and resubmit Im obviously allocated a new AFT and so the submit fails again but this doesn't feel right.

Ideally I would prefer the form action to only run on the domain it's on and not be able to execute the action from another site. I thought using AntiForgeryToken prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery.

If any of this is unclear, please let me know and I'll explain more.